# python comparing positive and negative numbers

Tags: python, comparison

I can't guess why I don't get anything printed when running this in python... it's like it's not considering negative numbers properly.

```
varA = -4
varB = 8
if type(varA)==str:
    print "string involved"
elif type(varB)==str:
    print "string involved"
elif varA>varB:
    print "bigger"
elif varA==varB:
    print "equal"
elif varA>varB:
    print "smaller"
```

Comment: Use isinstance(varA, str) instead of type(varA)==str

Comment: but even if I use isinstance I still get the same problem... it all works until I start playing with negative numbers which isn't making much sense to me

Comment: I know, it was a comment, not an answer

Answer (score 3):

change the last `elif varA>varB:` to `elif varA<varB:`. Just a typo.

To be safe when dealing with such problems, you can use `else` at last instead of `elif`:

```
elif varA>varB:
    print "bigger"
elif varA==varB:
    print "equal"
else:  #don't use elif 
    print "smaller"
```

Comment: thanks, typo stupid mistake

Comment: @user3289645 I suggest `else` instead of `elif`, see my edit ;)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the last `elif`: `elif varA>varB:`. It has the same condition as the 3rd. You should fix it to:

```
elif varA<varB:
```

By the way, as mentioned in comments, to check if instance of a type is better to use `isinstance` method than `type(obj)==str`.

Comment: thanks :) that's stupid mistake

Comment: @user3289645 No problem, that happen sometimes ;)

Answer (score 0):

Because none of the condition is True.

I guess you meant to write :

```
varA = -4
varB = 8
if type(varA)==str:
    print "string involved"
elif type(varB)==str:
    print "string involved"
elif varA>varB:
    print "bigger"
elif varA==varB:
    print "equal"
elif varA<varB: # And not "varA>varB" as above
    print "smaller"

Give --> smaller
```

Hope this answers your concern !